American checkers largest possible number of legal move choices from any board position
I want to know what is the maximum number of legal move choices from any board position, in the game of checkers, assuming official rules.
I'm creating a program that plays checkers, and for performance reasons, I need to know in advance the largest number of legal moves. I expect it to be quite low, like under 50, but just making a guess is not an option for me.
I searched for this, but couldn't find an answer. Maybe I missed something.
Edit:
Thinking for a moment, I think (one of) the largest theoretical number(s) of legal moves might be where all 12 pieces are kings, like in the position W:WK5,K6,K7,K8,K13,K14,K15,K16,K21,K22,K23,K24:BK30, which has 42 legal moves. That position is not valid and is not possible to occur. I'm more interested though in the largest possible moves from a valid checkers position. An upper bound might be fine.

I think it would be helpful if your post reminded us of the capturing rules in American checkers without needing to follow the rules link. In particular, it seems that kings cannot capture any distance along a line like in other versions of checkers.

How do you count branching capturing of stones? I'm sure that if you can arrange the board in such a way that you can capture all stones at once, there will be more than 50 possible moves that turn simple because of the different ways you could fork the jump

https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/18949/checkers-draughts-capture-all-pieces-in-1-move might be related

@Zibelas I knew about that post. In American checkers, one can capture at most 9 pieces and in that position, if I'm not mistaken, white has 9 possible moves (capture choices).

Considering the fact that the number of possible choices for the largest capture is 9, the largest number of moves should come from positions with no captures available, where there are as many kings as possible.
I just self played from the initial position a game where white has managed to create 7 kings, leaving it 7 * 4 = 28 legal moves in this position W:B28,K32:WK6,K7,K8,K14,K15,K16,K22.
If there exists a sequence of moves where white creates 8 kings and places the 8th king on square 23 before the 40-moves rule kicks in, then white would have 8 * 4 = 32 legal moves.
Going even further, if white creates 9 or 10 kings and places them in the same fashion, except for 9th and 10th kings somewhere on the edge, then white would have 8 * 4 + 1 * 2 = 34 or 8 * 4 + 2 * 2 = 36 legal moves.
If I can prove that white or black can never create more than 7, 8 or 9 kings from the initial position (because the other side is forced to capture), then I would have an answer.
36 moves seems a reasonable upper bound, since that would mean that the other side has only captured 2 pieces, which looks impossible. Even capturing only 3 pieces seems impossible.
My own answer doesn't satisfy me much, so I'm still looking for facts.

I am not asking if you have seen it, but have you heard about an American checkers game where the opponents work together to get each of their 12 playing pieces made into 12 kings?

No, I haven't heard about something like that. But as far as I know, it's impossible to not lose at least a few pieces due to forced captures.

There is a thread called "How many kings possible is it to have on the board at once?"  There are links in there about the supposed proved moves, but when I clicked them, the links no longer work.
